# Getting illegal_argument_exception", "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I am getting this query when i try to run below query from Postman

> { "error": { "root_cause": [ { "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
> "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set
> fielddata=true on [ID] in order to load fielddata in memory by
> uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use
> significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead." }

Here is the request

```
{

    "size": 11,

    "query": {

        "bool": {

            "filter": [

                {

                    "bool": {

                        "must": [

                            {

                                "term": {

                                    "search.doc.TypeId": {

                                        "value": 1,

                                        "boost": 1.0

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        ],

                        "adjust_negative": true,

                        "boost": 1.0

                    }

                }

            ],

            "adjust_negative": true,

            "boost": 1.0

        }

    },

    "sort": [

        {

            "ID": {

                "order": "desc"

            }

        }

    ]

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error it seems that the `objectID` field is of `text` type. By default, field data is disabled on text fields.

So, according to the error, first, you need to modify your index mapping, so that the text field have field data enabled. Modify your index mapping, as shown below

```
PUT <index-name>/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "objectID": {
      "type": "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

Now use the same search query as given in the question, to get the desired results.

Comment: Can we check what is the type field data query first ?

Comment: Yes i can see the type if key type

Comment: So do we have to re-index or can we change the type alone ?

Comment: @Anupam you can just update the index mapping, there is no need to reindex the data

Comment: Ohh if that can be done then its good but how can i do that ? I will create different question for that thanks

Comment: I have created a separate question for it please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70803955/how-to-update-index-mapping-to-update-fielddata-data-type