# How to update Index mapping to update fielddata data type

Tags: elasticsearch

I dont know how my field mapping changed from `keyword` to `text` but now its an issue and i need to change from `text` to `keyword` .
I have huge data so re-indexing will take 2 to 3 days time .Now we are looking way to update the index mapping so that the issue will be resolved .

In our lower environment the field data is still keyword  and in prod it is changed .
We are using AWS Elastic search 7.1

Please help .

This is what we want

```
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "objectID":{
        "type":"keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this gives us error

```
"type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
This is our search query
```

Finally we have upgraded our ES cluster so can that be the root cause of the issue ?
Its dynamic mapping for this filed .

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question, it states that now the field has the dynamic mapping. This means that your current index mapping for `objectId` field is of `text` type and multifield of `keyword` type

```
{
  "<index-name>" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "objectId" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You cannot change the mapping of `objectId` field from `text` to `keyword` type using Update mapping API. If you try to do so, you will get the below error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "mapper [name] cannot be changed from type [text] to [keyword]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "mapper [objectId] cannot be changed from type [text] to [keyword]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

So instead you can use `objectId.keyword` field (that is already created using dynamic mapping as stated in the question above), or you need to use the reindex API.

With the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html), you have to create a new index with the required index mapping, and then reindex the old data into the new index (based on the new index mapping)

Comment: @Anupam its been a long time ! Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue. TIA ;-)